# Trouble installing Cytoscape for Ubuntu

Tags: cytoscape

I am trying to install Cytoscape 3.9 for my Ubuntu system (22.04). I have installed Java 17 through OpenJDK as well as through the Adoptium link given on the installation page. Neither works. When I installed Cytoscape, I had no errors and went through the wizard without any issues. Here is the output I get when I run the system requirements checker:

```
##### Cytoscape System Requirements Checker for Linux #####

 - Target Cytoscape version: 3.9.0
 - Your Shell: bash

===== Checking Distribution =====

 - Linux Distribution: Ubuntu
 - Version: 22.04
 - Target Platform: x86_64

 - Pass: Distribution = Ubuntu
Fail: This Ubuntu version is not supported: 22.04
Supported versions are:
 - 14.04
 - 14.10
 - 15.04
 - 15.10
 - 16.04
 - 16.10
 - 17 04
 - 17 10
 - 18.04
 - 18.10
 - 20.04
 - 21.04

===== Checking Java Version =====

Error: "java" command is not available
You need to set PATH to $JAVA_HOME/bin.

Your current $PATH:

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin

===== Checking $JAVA_HOME =====

 - Pass: JAVA_HOME found: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64

===== Checking Connection to Cytoscape App Store =====

 - Checking connection to Cytoscape App Store...

apps.cytoscape.org has address xx.xx.xxx.xxx
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 50642    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0

 - Result: 200
 - Success!


----------------------------------------

Your system still has some issues.
Please fix those and re-run this script again.
```

When I try to run Cytoscape, the desktop application does nothing. When I try to run through terminal, this is the output:

```
Unrecognized option: -Xdock:icon=./framework/cytoscape_logo_512.png
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

The requirements checker states that my Ubuntu version isn't compatible, however, I'm using Cytoscape 3.10.0 and the version checker is for version 3.9.0, which should explain this.

Edit: running java -version gives me the correct output. So I know java is installed correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter what combination of Java I used with Cytoscape, nothing seemed to fix this issue. The solution for me ended up being that I needed to downgrade to Cytoscape 3.9.1 with Java 11. This version of the application runs perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

What you run through the terminal, you should use cytoscape.sh.  You do need Java 17 for 3.10.  The `-Xdock` stuff will be fixed in 3.10.1.

Comment: I tried running ./cytoscape.sh in my Cytoscape install location with Cytoscape 3.10.0, however this is the output I received:
`karaf.base: /opt/Cytoscape_v3.10.0/framework
JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64
Error installing bundle listed in startup.properties with url: mvn:org.apache.karaf.features/org.apache.karaf.features.core/4.3.7 and startlevel: 15`